# Count the number of different observations for every two columns and divide by the number of rows multiplied by two

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with header and row names.
Starting from the second column I would like to calculate the number of different observations (in that case 0 and 1 only) and divide them by the number of rows multiplied by two...

I am able to do this using COUNTIF from excel...but I was wondering if there is a way to do this in Python using pandas COUNTIF...

The data frame subset is as follows:

```
position    1X0812.0    1X0812.1    10192.0 10192.1 10316.0 10316.1 10349.0 10349.1 10418.0 10418.1 10482.0 10482.1
4035    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
4036    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
4083    0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
4119    0   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
4164    0   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
4185    1   1   0   1   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
4379    1   1   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
```

---

The desired output would be something like this in a new file:

```
0 0.5714 0.8571 0.7142 0.5000 1.0000 1.0000
1 0.4285 0.1428 0.2857 0.5000 0.0000 0.0000
```

---

Looking over the internet what could only get the sum of one observation (0 in this case) for the whole dataset...

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('query.tsv', sep='\t')
(df == 0).sum()
```

result:

```
position         0
10046.0     309027
10046.1     308117
10192.0     308117
10192.1     309027
             ...  
9656.1      171617
9860.0      261170
9860.1      226217
9878.0      309027
9878.1      309027
Length: 1565, dtype: int64
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counting the `1`s among the `0`s is equivalent to summing. So we can group the dataframe starting from the second column by the first part of the columns headers (before the `.`) and divide the sum by the count (alternatively you can directly use `mean` for the same).

```
g = df.iloc[:,1:].groupby(df.columns[1:].str.extract(r'(\d+)\.', expand=False), axis=1)
s = g.sum().sum() / g.count().sum()  # or s = g.mean().mean()
```

`s` is an unnamed Series representing the share of `1`s:

```
10046    0.428571
10192    0.142857
10316    0.285714
10349    0.500000
10418    0.000000
10482    0.000000
dtype: float64
```

From this Series we construct the desired resulting dataframe:

```
result = pd.concat([(1 - s).rename(0), s.rename(1)], axis=1).T
```

Result:

```
      10046     10192     10316  10349  10418  10482
0  0.571429  0.857143  0.714286    0.5    1.0    1.0
1  0.428571  0.142857  0.285714    0.5    0.0    0.0
```

Comment: Hi @Stef...It worked. The only thing is that when I apply it for my whole dataset some of the column names changes. Column names are a mix of numbers and characters (I've edited in the question too)...for example, 1X0812 will return only 0812..

Comment: So, I ended up finding a solution....just changed the ```(r'(\d+)\.'```to ```(r'(.*+)\.'```

Comment: in this case you can use`extract(r'(\w+)\.' ...`

Comment: hi @Stef...
I am wondering how I could have the Result: to display the numbers in only 4 decimals... e.g., 0.5714 (for the first result, instead of 0.571429)...
Perhaps I should apply the round function somewhere?
Thanks

Comment: @guidebortoli if you want to _change to value itself_ you can use [`round`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.round.html); if you just want to _change the output format_, i.e. the external representation you can set the `display.float_format` or use [`set_eng_float_format`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html#number-formatting)

Comment: Hi @Stef, I was wondering, if the dataset add another variable to be counted as another observation, e.g., "2" and now instead of only the 0 and 1 output I have also the frequency of 2s...I believe the strategy of counting the 1s and them later using the '(s - 1)' to get the 0s is wrong right? In other words, it only works for two different observations (in this case 0 and 1)...Thanks

Comment: Right, this approach only works for just two kinds of observations. To generalize you may want to look into [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html).